# Realm IN query based on junction table

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my Realm database I have 3 objects: `BodyPart`, `Exercise` & `Muscle`

Both `BodyPart` and `Exercise` have a collection of `Muscle`s, declared as `let muscles = List<Muscle>()` in their Realm definitions

What I am trying to do is retrieve all `Exercise` objects for a given `BodyPart`. In SQL I would probably do something along these lines:

```
select e.*
  from Exercise e
       inner join ExerciseMuscle em
               on e.ExerciseID = em.ExerciseID
       inner join BodyPartMuscle bpm
               on em.MuscleID = bpm.MuscleID
 where bpm.BodyPartID = 1
```

So what would be the simplest approach to achieve this in Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your model looks something like:

```
class Exercise: Object {
    let muscles = List<Muscle>()
}

class BodyPart: Object {
    let muscles = List<Muscle>()
}

class Muscle: Object {
}
```

And you want to walk from a given `BodyPart` to the `Exercises` that share `Muscle`s with it?

You can use `linkingObjects(_:forProperty:)` to walk from a `Muscle` instance back to `Exercise`s that reference it. It could look something like this:

```
extension BodyPart {
    var exercises: [Exercise] {
        return muscles.flatMap { $0.linkingObjects(Exercise.self, forProperty: "muscles") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's worked perfectly. And yes you did understand correctly, although I have `muscles` on `BodyPart` as a `linkingObjects` property rather than a `List` collection, but clearly that's not important and it works either way :p

Comment: As a further question on this, would it be possible to reference the `exercises` property in a `filter`. What I'd ideally like is to say `bodyPartsResults = realm.objects(BodyPart).filter("exercises.Count > 0")` but I get a runtime error saying `Property 'exercises' not found in object of type 'BodyPart'`

Comment: No, that's not something that Realm supports. I'd appreciate it if you could file an enhancement request at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new so that we can track adding it in the future.

Comment: Thanks, have raised that as an issue [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3008)